# Asymmetrik FHIR Server Core support FHIRCast?

Tags: node-fhir-server-core

I have established a "subscription" to updates on a specific "Bundle".  For some reason, the web hook is not firing.  Is FHIRCast supported on Asymmetrik's FHIR Server?  Here is my "subscription" json payload:

```
{
  "resourceType" : "Subscription",
  "status" : "active",
  "contact": [
    {
      "relationship": [
        {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0131",
              "code": "N"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "name": {
        "family": "du Marché",
        "_family": {
          "extension": [
            {
              "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/humanname-own-prefix",
              "valueString": "VV"
            }
          ]
        },
        "given": [
          "Bénédicte"
        ]
      },
      "telecom": [
        {
          "system": "phone",
          "value": "+33 (237) 998327"
        }
      ],
      "address": {
        "use": "home",
        "type": "both",
        "line": [
          "534 Erewhon St"
        ],
        "city": "PleasantVille",
        "district": "Rainbow",
        "state": "Vic",
        "postalCode": "3999",
        "period": {
          "start": "1974-12-25"
        }
      },
      "gender": "female",
      "period": {
        "start": "2012"
      }
    }
  ],
  "end" : "2021-02-07T13:28:17.239+02:00", 
  "reason" : "FHIR web hook", 
  "criteria" : "Bundle/af03af555d9eb78229619cfeac8767409fd22f72",
  "error" : "error note", 
  "channel" : { 
    "type" : "rest-hook", 
    "endpoint" : "https://localhost:5001/api/FHIRNotification", 
    "payload" : "application/fhir+json", 
    "header" : [""] 
  }
}
```

Perhaps I am missing an implementation step to add the subscription web hook functionality?

Thanks for the help!

Todd

Answer (score 0):

Currently we do not support FHIRCast out of the box since this is a facade server. To get FHIRCast working properly you would also probably need triggers or something else setup on the database.

Im not super familiar with FHIRCast personally but it does seem like there is some connection to a hub separate of the FHIR server as well.